# Changing a variable based on output

Tags: powershell, if-statement, read-host

Good Afternoon,
Just want to start by saying I am totally new with PS, and am really sorry if my approach to this is long winded or inaccurate.

I have a list of computernames that declared as individual Variables that my colleagues have provided me :

```
$Jon = "Abc1234"
$Mike = "Abc6789"
```

- another 10 hostnames

I then ask the user if they want to send the files to another PC :

```
$Targetuser = Read-Host 'Who would you like to send it to?'
```

What I would like is the output from the above to change to the hostname, but I am unsure of how to do this.
Essentially, if the output was Mike, to change the `$targetuser` variable to `$Abc6789`

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable?view=powershell-7.1) seems pretty good for the task at hand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically named variables is almost *always a bad idea*. Instead, use a dictionary type, like a hashtable:

```
# Define user->host dictionary
$Hostnames = @{
  Jon  = "Abc1234"
  Mike = "Abc6789"
}

# Ask user for target user
$TargetUser = Read-Host 'Who would you like to send it to?'

# Keep asking until the enter an actual user name
while(-not $Hostnames.ContainsKey($TargetUser)){
  Write-Host "No hostname found for user '${targetUser}'!"
  Write-Host "Choose one of:"
  Write-Host ($Hostnames.Keys -join "`n")
  $TargetUser = Read-Host 'Who would you like to send it to?'
} 

# Get the associated hostname
$TargetHost = $Hostnames[$TargetUser]

# copy file to $TargetHost
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is amazing! That has solved my issue. Honestly, wish I could buy you a beer!

Comment: @ChristopherRetford Maybe you'll get the chance one day ^_^ For now, all I ask is you consider marking my answer "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left :-)

Comment: It's the least I can do friend. Thank you again so much. I am very grateful. Honestly PS has opened my world up with the things it can do and I am learning so so much from people like yourselves!